# Run Node Script with ASP Classic

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, backend

I'd like to know what's the proper way of running a node script from within a ASP Classic / VBScript page.

I've tried to open a notepad file didn't work:

```
<%
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"
 %>
```

What I really want to do:

```
<%
Response.Expires=-1
session.LCID=1046

Dim user, numNF, programArgs, programPath

numNF = Request.Form("numNF")
user = Request.Form("user")
programPath = "C:\aloha\nodeProgram.js"
programArgs = numNF & " " &  user

Dim oShell
Set oShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

oShell.Run("""C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"" ""C:\aloha\nodeProgram.js"" ""numNF"" ""user""", 0, True)

Set oShell = Nothing

 %>
```

Nothing Works!

Comment: Remember: this script is running on the web server, not on the end user's computer, and _in the context of the user running the web service_. If you check task manager on the server, the notepad app _is probably actually running_ on a virtual private desktop you can't see because it belongs to the Network Service (or similar) account.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Thank you for the support, I'm using IIS as the Web Server. From what you said, I neither have access to the node location on the web server nor my .js file is showing up on IIS Manager. How should I proceed to be able to run a node script from the web server?

Comment: I don't know if it's an option for your particular file, but you can run JavaScript server side in Classic ASP without Node.  Strictly speaking it supports JScript, which is a Microsoft dialect of JavaScript, and it hasn't been updated for a while so your code would need to be compatible with IE7.  If that applies then you could call it with `<script language = "javascript" runat="server" src="pathto/yourjsfile.js">`

Comment: Did you check the ISAPI ASP filter had `EXECUTE` permission on scripts?

Comment: Aloha ?  Is this a POS machine for a restaurant  or hotel?

Answer (score 0):

As I was not managing to execute the node script with an ASP page, I changed the POST request url to an ASP.NET page with the following code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Expires = -1;
        Session["LCID"] = 1046;

        string user, numNF, programArgs, programPath;

        numNF = Request.Form["numNF"];
        user = Request.Form["user"];
        programPath = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aloha.js";
        programArgs = numNF + " " + user;

        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = programPath + " " + programArgs;
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
        
    }
</script>
```

Now it works. Hope it helps!

Comment: Not it works?  Or Now it works?

Comment: Not really what I would call an answer to the problem.

Comment: Until I know, the Node.js javascript  is not compatible with the ASP jScript (yes J-S-C-R-I-P-T ) this is a non standar implementation of an ancient version of javascript (pre ECMA)

Comment: @Rafael that is true but the OP is only trying to use VBScript to run node from the command line no reference is made to running JScript.